# Why doesn't Vodafone Mobile broadband work in UK?

Tags: 12.04, 3g, huawei, vodafone

I am trying to commission a UK Huawei K3772 3G dongle in the Linux embedded platform. Between the card and the dial-up, this process works normally. The problem lies in the dial-up connection where a dialing script error occurs. An example of my terminal output is as follows below.

How can I solve this problem? Please give me some advice.

```
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Serial connection established.
using channel 5
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa34dc1ef> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <accomp> <pcomp> <asyncmap 0x0> <mru 1500> <magic 0x54c
> <auth chap MD5>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <accomp> <pcomp> <asyncmap 0x0> <mru 1500> <magic 0x54c
> <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa34dc1ef> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <5effc5b4431d5f70aca7507696fc1150>, name = "HUAWEI_C
HAP_SRVR"]
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <cb7593075f09ab0fa445a78712d7806b>, name = "web"]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "Welcome!!"]
CHAP authentication succeeded: Welcome!!
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe -H -M -S -L -D -C> <bsd v1 15>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x2 80 fd 01 01 00 0d 12 06 00 00 00 00 15 03 2f]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Serial connection established.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is based on [this answer](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1114), but whenever possible I have used the terminal commands instead of just their descriptions.

**1.** Open the terminal and type:

```
cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d
sudo touch 12d1:1526
sudo nano 12d1:1526
```

This will open the 12d1:1526 file for editing in nano text editor. The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Copy the following text into the nano editor window:

```
# Vodafone K3772 (Huawei)

TargetVendor=  0x19d2
#TargetProduct= not known yet

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the 12d1:1526 file. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

**2.** Open the `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules` file for editing in nano by running: `cd '/lib/udev/rules.d/' && sudo nano 40-usb_modeswitch.rules`. You need to add the following two lines to 40-usb_modeswitch.rules putting an empty space before the two lines and another empty space after the two lines:

```
# Vodafone (Huawei) K3772
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1526", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the 40-usb_modeswitch.rules file. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

**3.** Plug in your modem in and wait at least 10 seconds. After this run the `lsusb` command in the terminal. There should be a device ID starting with `12d1` but most likely different than `12d1:1526`. The changed part of the ID (after the colon) is your new `TargetProduct` value (prepended by these two characters: `0x` ). Edit your `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d` file (the same file that you edited previously in Step 1) accordingly as root in nano, removing the comment sign (the <kbd>#</kbd> character) at the start of the TargetProduct line.

**4.** Unplug the modem and plug it in again. Wait ... (Huawei modems need up to 20 seconds for the mode switch.). Run `dmesg` in the terminal and you should see something like `GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSBx`. This means that your modem is ready to use.